# Can CanActivate in Angular continue after navigating to another route?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

In an auth guard when authentication is missing I want to display Facebook login. Wonder if it will work to do `router.navigate(['login'])` in `canActivate` to trigger authentication and return async result of the login or will it be interrupted by the `router.navigate` call. Wonder about proper and simple flow here.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible.  you can also use navigateByUrl to get to facebook

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private userService: UserService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (this.userService.isValid()) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/login'], {
        queryParams: {
          return: state.url
        }
      });
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

code snippet credits go to / more examples can be found on : http://gnomeontherun.com/2017/03/02/guards-and-login-redirects-in-angular/

Comment: thanks! just to precise, instead of `false` I'd like to return a `Promise` or `Observable` of authentication result triggered by navigating to login to avoid the gimmick with where to continue after success. Another option would be to show the login component without use of router. The thing is that I'd like to put a guard in an external library which makes passing the component cumbersome.

Comment: Hmm, its early here. not really seeing the issue yet.  you can do something like return url to navigate back if authentication is succesful.  you can return Promises / Observables as stated in the CanActivate interface, but i have no idea of how this could be used.

Comment: I just don't like the common approach of navigating again to the original route (and dealing with origin url at all)